# Previously working LoginwithProvider suddenly started throwing errors (Client Managed Login)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, azure, azure-mobile-services

I've been using the below code without any problems since the beginning of the project. All of a sudden since last 3-4 days I'm getting this error being returned.

Last time it happened 2 days back, I solved it by restarting my mac. 
This time that also is not working. What could be the issue ??

This occurs on the simulator as well as the actual phone. All Facebook logins are valid and working fine otherwise.

[image]

Comment: Anybody ?? Totally stuck because of this now.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I did a "restart" of the mobile service on the Azure Mobile Services Console. Had never seen that button for "restart" there.Gave it a shot.

I still do not know why it occurred though and I'm hoping I wouldn't need to do this too frequently when the app goes live.